# How to make a wavy border line to separate background images in html5/css?

Tags: css, html, web

I'm looking to create a wavy line border/separation between 2 .png textures for a background for a website like the one below:

[image]

It was done in a software like illustrator or something for the mock ups to a web page and I was wondering is it possible to recreate it using html5/css or is there a free software that it can be drawn in although this would be a last resort as I'm not the most artistic?
All help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your backgrounds are that simple and loopable, you could create the black one with the wave (loopable in x-dimension) and then use multiple backgrounds.

```
background: url(black.png) left top repeat-x, url(brown.png) left top repeat
```